# Scheduled index not working / Products show after running manual index

Tags: magento2, cron, indexing, magento-ce

I have a Magento CE 2.1 site. Products are not showing up until after a manual index is run.

Index is set to run on schedule.
Cron is running

```
*/1 * * * * php -f /path/to/Magento2.1CE/bin/magento cron:run  &> /dev/null
*/1 * * * * php -f /path/to/Magento2.1CE/update/cron.php &> /dev/null
*/1 * * * * php -f /path/to//Magento2.1CE/bin/magento setup:cron:run &> /dev/null
```

Tested it this way

```
php -f /path/to/Magento2.1CE/bin/magento cron:run

Ran jobs by schedule.
```

Comment: I'm not sure about config with `php -f`. Try to replace with the absolute file system path to your PHP binary: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/comp-mgr/prereq/prereq_cron.html

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I tried what you suggested and it did not work

Comment: You check the table `cron_schedule`? There is any cron job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Khoa started me on this answer:

This is a shared server from Nexcess and I am under the impression there is multiple versions of PHP running.

The indexing started to work when I switched to

```
/opt/nexcess/php56u/root/usr/bin/php
```

Which I easily found like this

```
$ which php
/opt/nexcess/php56u/root/usr/bin/php
```

Indexing is working fine now.